# Can't add two variables via a loop to a variable

Tags: python, addition

```
{'sm': ['q', 0.25, 1000], 'Bug Out Bag': ['q', 0.25, 100000000]}
```

Calculate for total amount, here's my code:

```
single_or_all_total = input('\nDo you want 1 bag or all the bags? (type: 1 for 1 bag, 2 for all bags)\n')
#calculate for a single bag
if int(single_or_all_total) == 1:
    single_bag_total = input('\nWhich bag? (e.g. type: small for the "small" bag)\n')
    if single_bag_total in coins_in_the_bag:
        total = coins_in_the_bag[single_bag_total][1] * coins_in_the_bag[single_bag_total][2]
        print('The total for bag {} was {}'.format(single_bag_total, total))
        #print(total)
    elif single_bag_total not in coins_in_the_bag:
        print('Sorry, this was not a valid bag. Please re-run file.')
    else:
        print('An error occurred, please re-run script.')

#calculate total for all bags
elif single_or_all_total == 2:
    total=0
    single_bag_total=0
    for coin in coins_in_the_bag:
        total += coins_in_the_bag[single_bag_total][1] * coins_in_the_bag[single_bag_total][2]
    print(total)
```

the problem is, when I run this, it returns nothing.

I can make my code hit the `if int(single_or_all_total) == 1:`, but if i input a `2` it doesnt crash at all, it just doesnt return anything.

I'm simply trying to loop through `coins_in_the_bag`, while adding each `value` to the `total` var:
`( coins_in_the_bag[single_bag_total][1] * coins_in_the_bag[single_bag_total][2] )` but it is not outputting anything.

What am i doing wrong here?

**Updated Error**

```
    total += coins_in_the_bag[single_bag_total][1] * coins_in_the_bag[single_bag
_total][2]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never hit the loop you suspected.

From your use of `print` as a function (and your conversions of `single_or_all_total`), I'm going to deduce that you are using Python 3.

Then, `input` returns a simple string, just like `raw_input` in Python 2.

You compare `int(single_or_all_total)` to `1` (which is fine, and works), and then `single_or_all_total` to `2`. Note that this second version misses the conversion to a number - the string in `single_or_all_total` is never going to be equal to `2`, only `"2"`.

Instead, try `elif int(single_or_all_total) == 2` or `elif single_or_all_total == "2"`

Comment: Good catch, although, this doesnt quite fix it all. Can you look at the updated error above, which still has to do with this "total" var.

Comment: `total` is not yet defined. Try putting `total = 0` before the loop

Comment: Please see updated, now giving me.     total += coins_in_the_bag[single_bag_total][1] * coins_in_the_bag[single_bag
_total][2]
KeyError: 0

Comment: I don't know your exact data, so this is mostly guessing, but from the top branch of your `if` statement, I'm going to suggest you try using `coin` instead of `single_bag_total` here (because `coin` iterates over the same values as `single_bag_total` does above)